# Registering Different types of Users in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-settings

I wont be needing to write codes much,I just need an idea.I am trying to make users in two different categories.That is a User can either have a Profile or Shop both not both.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,editable=True)

class Shop(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,editable=True)
```

I want all users to either have one of both,They will register with the same form without being able to switch from one to another once they have registered for it.As at now what I'm doing is If i dont want a shop-owned User to have the previlege of a profile i do

```
def post_product(request):
    try:
        if bool(request.user.profile)==False:
            .....
    except:
        pass
```

But I have to do this for all views that require previledges. I want something site-wide that i can put in settings or put at the view like `@login_required` .Please how can I go about this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per answer given by Prabhakar, you should use django auth groups.
But, if you want to write your custom permission class, you could also do it.

1) Assuming file name -> self_defined_permission.py

```
 from rest_framework import permissions
 from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

 class ShopPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
     def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
         '''
         check user group. Assuming you keep users having profile in group 1 and shop in group 2
         '''
         shop_gp = Group.objects.get(id=2)
         if shop_gp in request.user.groups.all():
             return True
         else:
             return False
        '''
            similarly you could write permission class for profile owners
        '''
```

2) In your class based view

```
     from self_defined_permission import ShopPermissions

     class SomeView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
         ...
         permission_classes = (ShopPermissions, )
```

3) In case you are using function based view.

```
    from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes

    @permission_classes((ShopPermissions, ))
    def some_view(request):
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def is_shop(user):
   return Shop.objects.filter(user=user).exists()

def is_normal_user(user):
   return Profile.objects.filter(user=user).exists()

@user_passes_test(is_shop)
def only_for_shops(request):
   return render(request, 'edit_price_list.html')
```